# Use chrome for scraping with selenium in .net 8 API

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I'm developing an backend API in C# with .net 8.
On this API, there is a part of scraping scripts that use `OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome` to open urls and get HTML elements including javascript :

```cs
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("no-sandbox");
options.AddArguments("--headless");
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);
```

It works well when directly run it with dotnet run, but I can't succeed to make it work ith docker.

I have a dockerfile with the following structure

```cs
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 as build
WORKDIR "/src"


COPY ["/Solution.Project1/Solution.Project1.csproj", "Solution.Project1/"]
COPY ["/Solution.Project2/Solution.Project2.csproj", "Solution.Project2/"]
COPY ["/Solution.Project3/Solution.Project3.csproj", "Solution.Project3/"]
COPY ["/Solution.Project4/Solution.Project4.csproj", "Solution.Project4/"]

RUN dotnet restore "Solution.Project1/Solution.Project1.csproj" -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json 

COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/Solution.Project1"
RUN dotnet build "Solution.Project1.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/build

FROM build as publish
RUN dotnet publish "Solution.Project1.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/publish

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Solution.Project1.dll"]
```

I tried to put this part of code somewhere in the dockerfile, but nothing changed

```
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
```

I'm still having the following error when calling the method needing the driver after building and running the docker image:

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchDriverException: Unable to obtain chrome using Selenium Manager; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Error starting process: /app/selenium-manager/linux/selenium-manager  --browser "chrome" --output json
> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Selenium Manager process exited abnormally with 65 code: /app/selenium-manager/linux/selenium-manager  --browser "chrome" --output json
> Standard Output >>
> {
> "logs": [
> {
> "level": "ERROR",
> "timestamp": 1706129527,
> "message": "error sending request for url (https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/last-known-good-versions-with-downloads.json): error trying to connect: dns error: failed to lookup address information: Name does not resolve"
> }
> ],
> "result": {
> "code": 65,
> "message": "error sending request for url (https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/last-known-good-versions-with-downloads.json): error trying to connect: dns error: failed to lookup address information: Name does not resolve",
> "driver_path": "",
> "browser_path": ""
> }
> }
>
> <<
>
> at OpenQA.Selenium.SeleniumManager.RunCommand(String fileName, String arguments)

I tried many others solutions I found on the forums but nothing is working.

I don't even succeed to find in my container file where the "chromedriver" is.

Can someone help me to understand ?

If everything can be in a single dockerfile it would be great for me

I tried a lot of solutions explained on several forums, including "selenium", "chromedriver", and "docker" words.

I tried them all and it didn't work for me, either I have an error while building the image because something like "unable to fetch", either I have an error using the API.

I just tried another thing, with only this code I can find the chromedriver file on the container :

```
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome:latest AS base1

RUN sudo apt-get install -y wget xvfb unzip
# Set up the Chrome PPA -> (not sure if needed)
RUN sudo wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
RUN sudo su -c "echo 'deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list"

# Update the package list
RUN sudo apt-get update -y

# Set up Chromedriver Environment variables and install chrome
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION 114.0.5735.90
ENV CHROME_VERSION 114.0.5735.90-1
RUN wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chrome.deb "https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb"
RUN sudo apt install -y --allow-downgrades /tmp/chrome.deb
RUN sudo rm /tmp/chrome.deb

ENV CHROMEDRIVER_DIR /chromedriver
RUN sudo mkdir $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Download and install Chromedriver
RUN sudo wget -q --continue -P $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
RUN sudo unzip $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR/chromedriver* -d $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR
```

I needed to add "sudo" somewhere and adapt with --allow-downgrades and little other subjects

**But if I add my other previous part to have my .Net app, it deletes all the previous things done before for selenium**.

I don't understand well how this is working

Comment: the latest versions of Selenium will automatically download chromedriver and/or browser.  It sounds like a connectivity issue in the docker.   Check docker network inspect: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_inspect/

Comment: Thanks, I tried different things : 

Either I specify the path ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService("bin/Debug/net8.0/") but I get this error running with docker :

An error occurred trying to start process 'bin/Debug/net8.0/chromedriver' with working directory '/app'. No such file or directory

Either I don't specify the path ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService() and I get this error OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:46415/

I have 3 networks : bridge, host & none : which one should I inspect ?

Comment: never used docker before... but I believe there are docker files you can use which are already setup for Selenium.

Comment: I don't know how, but I think I succeeded to make it work without specifying anythilg else in dockerfile. I just only get an error now due to db connexion through container (I dind't set up that yet)

Comment: Finally I still have the issue.. WebDriverException: Cannot start the driver service on http://host.docker.internal:4444/. Same with "localhost". On internet I only find examples where selenium is in a separated container, not with the app

Comment: the driver is going to try to start a service running on localhost.  That is used to send http commands and receive responses to/from the browser's wire protocol.  By default it will just look for an open port on localhost....

Comment: @browsermator do you know how I can do to run that ? Outside docker container, my app works. But not inside. I'd like the chrome driver to be usable inside the same container as my .net app, so that my .net app can reach it

Comment: I don't.  But from a quick google I see that docker images are setup to be grids.  It sounds like you can connect between docker images though, so you can just use another docker image as a grid/hub you call from your main docker image.  When initializing the driver, you'd just set the URL to the grid hub.  Ex:  driver = new RemoteWebDriver(GridUrl, options);  See here for Docker files: https://hub.docker.com/u/selenium  So your code runs in the the main container, and calls to the other container where the driver/browser runs.

Comment: though come to think of it, if one of those containers can run a grid, you should also be able to call it locally.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue related to newer versions of Google Chrome, specifically caused by version selection for versions 115 and newer, as mentioned [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection)

To address this problem, I implemented the following fix in my Dockerfile:

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gnupg wget curl unzip && \
    wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends google-chrome-stable && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

#Rest of the code 
#Build
```

I didn't need to download Chromedriver, but if the above solution doesn't work, you can download it like this:

Note: Removing echo "" at the end fails Docker build (I'm not sure why).

```
RUN export CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=$(curl -s "https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE"); \
    wget -q --continue -P /chromedriver "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/${CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION}/chromedriver_linux64.zip"; \
    echo ""
```

And in your C# code:
C# Code

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--headless"); 
options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox"); 
options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); 

using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options))
```

Comment: Without the download: /root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/121.0.6167.85/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Cannot assign requested address (localhost:38721)

Comment: With the download : 

/root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/121.0.6167.85/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Cannot assign requested address (localhost:45671) 

Seems to be the same issue, I think something is missing on my side but I don't find what